# Scrapy - Output does not appear

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

Good morning everyone,

I have an issue when using Scrapy. I would like to get the data contained in the column "commune" of the table from this url: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_communes_de_Belgique_par_population

Here is my Spider:

```
import scrapy
import json

class communes_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "communes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_communes_de_Belgique_par_population'
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        yield response.css('table.wikitable td a::text').getall()
```

I'm using the terminal to crawl the page:

```
scrapy crawl communes
```

However it does not output the data of the column "commune". Therefore I cannot store them on a json file. Does someone have an insight on what is going on here ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None but you are returning a list

Please change your code into this

```
import scrapy
import json

class communes_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "communes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_communes_de_Belgique_par_population'
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {'communes':response.css('table.wikitable td a::text').getall()}
```